# Facebook Graph API: Update Page Post Message

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, coldfusion

I'm trying to use the facebook graph api to update the message on a previous post. I have the original post id and a valid never ending user access token. I am getting a "success" message back, but the post message is NOT getting updated.

```
<CFHTTP METHOD="POST" URL="https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/#qPost.PostID#?message=#URLEncodedFormat(Message)#&access_token=#AccessToken#" THROWONERROR="YES">
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Accept-Encoding" value="*" />
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="TE" value="deflate;q=0" />     
</CFHTTP>
```

Success Message:

[image: Success Message]

I'm going off the facebook graph details here (i know it says publish_actions permission has been removed), but certainly there has to be a way to update a page post via the graph api.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.2/post#updating

Also when I say I'm trying to update the message, basically the text that is written in the post (see image)

[image: Text I'm Trying To Update]

Comment: also, the original post was done using the graph api

Comment: try: <cfhttpparam type="header" name="message" value="#URLEncodedFormat(Message)#" /> Also the PHP example passes the access token

Comment: i've added <cfhttpparam type="header" name="message" value="#URLEncodedFormat(Message)#" />, and still get the "success" message back, but the post message still does not get updated.

Answer (score 2):

I got this figured out, i was not using the full `postid` in my request. When the original post was created it sends back a post id, which is a combination of the `pageid` and the `postid` (with an underscore in between), it looks like this below, with the first part being the `pageid` and the one after the underscore being the `postid`, I was only putting the 2nd part as the `postid`:

```
 334797943936653_2003899366299670
```

It's funny that i would still get a "success" even though I had an invalid `postid`.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation example states

> POST /v3.2/post-id HTTP/1.1
>   Host: graph.facebook.com
>
> message=This+is+a+test+message

So `message` is part of the POST body. But your code sends the `message` as part of the query string. Solution: Move `message` and `access_token` to the body.

```
<cfhttp method="POST" url="https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/#qPost.PostID#" throwOnError="true">

    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Accept-Encoding" value="*" />
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="TE" value="deflate;q=0" />

    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="message" value="#Message#" />
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="access_token" value="#AccessToken#" />

</cfhttp>
```

Encoding is done by `cfhttpparam` automatically, so keep the readable/desired text in the `message` variable.